# if else mysql syntax

Tags: mysql

Can anybody help me in this syntax? I don't know what wrong am I doing!

When I try to execute this code:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_username = '$user_username') 
THEN
UPDATE user SET user_name='$name',user_profession='$profession',user_address='$address',user_avatar='$NewImageName'
ELSE 
INSERT INTO user (user_name,user_profession,user_address,user_avatar) VALUES ('$name','$profession','$address','$NewImageName';
```

I get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_username = '111') THEN UPDATE user SE' at line 1
```

I don't know what is wrong with this code!

Comment: @tsHunter yes he does. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html

Comment: use `insert .. on duplicate key update` syntax

Comment: I was trying to `UPDATE` the table when the `IF EXISTS` part is TRUE. Else, I wanted to `INSERT` into the table.

Comment: I don't need an `ON DUPLICATE` key.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding an `END IF` after the `INSERT INTO...` statement?

Comment: There also needs to be a `)` before the `;` at the end of your VALUES statement.

Comment: @NirmalyaGhosh Great! If this answered the question for you would you mind accepting it as the answer? Thanks.

Comment: @NirmalyaGhosh I see it now.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

you need `ON DUPLICATE KEY`

```
INSERT INTO user (user_name,user_profession,user_address,user_avatar)
VALUES ('$name','$profession','$address','$NewImageName'
   ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE user SET user_name='$name',
                user_profession='$profession',
                user_address='$address',
                user_avatar='$NewImageName'
```

you must have column `user_name` as `UNIQUE`

if its not unique do this

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE user ADD UNIQUE (user_name);
```

Comment: he doesn't need an `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, he needs a working `IF` statement. Your proposing another solution, but this is not an answer, is it?

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code did the trick for me:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_username = '$user_username'");
if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE user SET user_name='$name',user_profession='$profession',user_address='$address',user_avatar='$NewImageName' WHERE user_username = '$user_username'");
}
else
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (user_name,user_profession,user_address,user_avatar) VALUES ('$name','$profession','$address','$NewImageName') WHERE user_username = '$user_username'");
}
```